# Background Subtractor

Tags: python, opencv, background-subtraction

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.9 on Python 2.7. I am trying to use OpenCV's background subtraction. It's supposed to somehow determine from the video input, what objects are in the foreground and what others are in the background (?). However, the resulting output looks as if it just subtracts the first frame from subsequent frames. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

BSGuy = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()


while(1):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = BSGuy.apply(frame)

    cv2.imshow('Frame', fgmask)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm trying to upload an image to clarify, but I see I need to have reputation 10 to post. (I'm new here.) The problem is that in addition to a present 'image' of me, an initial 'image' of me when the program started running remains on the screen. How do I remove it?

Thanks.

Comment: first of all, background subtraction is nothing magic, the algorithm computes a background model (starting with the first frame) and updates that model. So for example if your camera is moving, standard background subtraction won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have used `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`. That takes input from your camera.

Latest version of OpenCV is 4.3.0.

I used `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()` instead of `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()`

Code:

```
BSGuy = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
```

Background Subtractor works just fine through this process. As you mentioned there's no extra initial 'image' remains on the screen.